# Custom Incoming Mail Domain With Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, email, dns

I have set up a custom domain for my google app engine application, which accepts incoming email.  While this works great if you want to use an email address like example@example.appspotmail.com, I would like to use a custom domain like example@example.com.  Is it possible to do this?

A solution that will not work, is to simply use Google Apps to forward emails to the appspotmail address.  This is because I accept emails to any number of email addresses at my domain, and I would need to set up this forwarding for each one - simply not doable.

Thanks for any help!
Devon

Comment: To clarify, I would like to redirect *@mydomain.com to *@appid.appspotmail.com so mail sent to test@mydomain.com be redirected to test@appid.appspotmail.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

App Engine doesn't currently support receiving email on custom domains. You'd need to point your MX records to a service that supports mail redirection, and have it redirect all addresses to your appspotmail subdomain.

Comment: Do you know of such a service?

Comment: ZoneEdit offer MailForward: http://www.zoneedit.com/ . DynDns also offer similar services: http://www.dyndns.com/services/

Comment: here's the issue in the google bug tracker: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2314

Comment: Hi all, are there any updates regarding this matter?

Comment: We use GSuite for this.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you have many different email addresses you want to forward to appspotmail and due to the large number of addresses it would be time prohibitive to set up forwarding for each one. One solution I admit isn't perfect but works well is to set up a single email account that forwards all email to appspotmail. Then in Google apps make that email address a Catch all email address. What this does is that any email address that does not match an existing email address will go to the catch all email adress then it will be forwarded to appspotmail. With this trick you must only verify a single email address.
It will also allow you to specify a few addresses that don't go to appspotmail by creating the email accounts if you need to. This solution allows you to have an unlimited number of addresses forwarded to appspotmail.

Solution 2 allows a limited number of addresses forwarded to appspotmail. Create an email address that forwards to appspotmail then you can assign that address multiple "nicknames" which are aliases for that account and will also forward. You can create up to 30 email aliases for an individual account. If you need more create another account and repeat. The maximum number of email aliases for your Google Apps account is 10 times the number of user accounts. Using this technique if you have a free account and you signed up after May 10, 2011 you can make up to 310 forwarding addresses.  If you have a free account and signed up before May 10, 2011 the limit is 1550 forwarding addresses using this technique.