# Receive and process email without running own SMTP server

Tags: email, smtp, google-apps-script, mta

Trying to put together this:

[Trigger Google Apps Script by email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420435/trigger-google-apps-script-by-email)

with this:

[Custom Incoming Mail Domain With Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698802/custom-incoming-mail-domain-with-google-app-engine)

So that ultimately we can process emails to a scalable inbox @ourgoogleappsdomain.com.  Google apps accounts slap a limit of 10,000 a day, which way doesn't work for us.
Services that seem to supply this feature, just not at the scale we need, include:

1. http://mailnuggets.com
2. http://www.mailhooks.com
3. http://www.email2http.net

So yes - trying to see what we can do to avoid rolling our own mail server here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure Google Apps to route incoming messages to that address to a separate SMTP server ([split delivery](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2685650)).

You can then use any third-party SMTP server to receive your messages and run your code (typically by sending HTTP POST requests)

The following services can be used to receive large mail volumes:

- http://www.mailgun.com/pricing
- https://postmarkapp.com/pricing
- http://www.cloudmailin.com/plans
- http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html

Comment: As we now know, this doesn't bypass our sending limit.