# how to forward email using MX record in DNS

Tags: dns, mx-record, email-forwarding

I have domain name(exmple.com) and DNS. I want email at admin@exmple.com is forwarded to mymail@gmail.com. there is any way to forwarding using MX recoder in DNS. If it is possible tell me how to update MX record ? 
Thanks

Comment: This question is answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382003/using-mx-records-to-forward-email-to-another-domain

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using MX Records to Forward Email to Another Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382003/using-mx-records-to-forward-email-to-another-domain)

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. The MX record answers the question "To send an email to a given domain name, which host should I contact?". Since what you want to do involves the local parts of email addresses, it falls outside of the realm of DNS.